# SQL Server: getting data from second table when condition is matched wihtout duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, duplicates

I have 2 tables (user, userContact) that are connected by a column `userID`.

They're structured somewhat like this:

Table **User**:

```
[User_id]
[User_Name]
```

Table **UserContact**:

```
[UserContact_id]
[User_id]
[UserContact_Type]
[UserContact_Description]
```

So, for the same `[User_id]` there can be multiple [`UserContact_id`].

My problem is: I want to build a join that returns EVERY `[User_id]` from Table `User` AND includes `[UserContact_Description]` WHEN `[UserContact_Type]` is equal to 3, but do not duplicate results.

What have I tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    u.[User_id],
    CASE
       WHEN c.[UserContact_Type] = 3
          THEN c.[UserContact_Description]
    END AS UserContact
FROM 
    Table.user AS u
LEFT JOIN 
    Table.userContact AS c ON u.[User_id] = c.[User_id]
```

And I get something like this:

```
User_id    UserContact
----------------------
    6009    NULL
    7010    NULL
    7010    user7010@email.com
    7012    NULL
    8007    NULL
    8007    user8007@email.com
```

It returns every result from `Table.user`, but it duplicates the data for every `[User_id]` associated to a different `[UserContact_Type]` rather than 3.

And what I need is to return `[UserContact_Description]` ONLY when `[UserContact_Type] = 3`.

This is my first question on StackOverflow. I hope I've done it right, but feel free to point any mistakes I've been made within the post.

Thank you all very much.

EDIT:

As you can see in the table below, `[User_id]` is never related to the same `[UserContact_Type]`

```
UserContact_id  User_id UserContact_Type
40107           4747        1
40108           4747        5
40109           4747        3
41107           5748        6
41108           5748        3
41215           6009        1
41216           6009        6
42222           7010        3
42223           7010        6
43214           8007        3
```

What do I want: WHEN I find an `[User_id]` related to a `[UserContact_Type] = 3`, return its `[UserContact_Description]`. If the `[User_id]` has no correlation to the condition, return nothing and leave the column `[UserContact_Description]` empty or null.

The thing I want to avoid is results like this:

```
User_id UserContact
    6009    NULL
    7010    NULL
    7010    user7010@email.com
```

The [User_id] = 6009 is fine, but the [User_id] = 7010 is duplicated, and this is my problem. I want all [User_id]. But i only need to fullfill the UserContact column with [UserContact_Type] equal to 3.

Hope its clearer now.

Comment: So those `NULL` rows shouldn't be there?

Comment: I think you just need to add another join criteria. Like `LEFT JOIN Table.userContact as c ON u.[User_id] = c.[User_id] AND c.[UserContact_Type] = 3` Assuming you know that there is only a single record for that type in the table at all times.

Comment: Also, `TABLE` and `USER` are reserved keywords in T-SQL and should be avoided for object names and aliases. If those are your names then you would need to delimit identify then. Also, do you *really* have a schema called `[table]`? That would be like have a table called `[column]` :/

Comment: @Larnu no problem with NULL rows. The problem is the duplicated [User_id] rows. 
And no worries, names are fictional for example proposes =)

Comment: Try using ROW_NUMBER()

Comment: @ggon Do you have a unique constraint/index on (user_id, usercontact_type) in usercontact table? If not, then you need to add it or stop assuming (and misleading others) that based on "as you can see ...".  Without that constraint, your assumption will eventually be found out and be proven incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a left join of the tables and conditional aggregation:

```
select u.[User_id], u.[User_Name],
  max(case 
      when c.[UserContact_Type] = 3 then c.[UserContact_Description] 
      else null 
    end 
  ) as UserContact_Description 
from [User] u left join [userContact] c
on c.[User_id] = u.[User_id]
group by u.[User_id], u.[User_Name]
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8118dfbe80f4707eab890b3774a8b9a8).

Comment: Thank you very much! This one did the job.

Answer (score 1):

Move the `c.[UserContact_Type] = 3` condition to `ON` . If ONLY [UserContact_Type] = 3 needed, omit `LEFT`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.[User_id],
                c.[UserContact_Description] as UserContact
    FROM [Table.user] AS u
    LEFT JOIN [Table.userContact] as c
      ON u.[User_id] = c.[User_id]
         AND c.[UserContact_Type] = 3
```

Comment: This brings me only the [User_id] that are related to a [UserContact_Type] equal to 3. But i need ALL [User_id] from table [Table.user] and results in column [UserContact_Description] when theres an [User_id] related to a [UserContact_Type] = 3. Otherwise the column [UserContact_Description] should be NULL, but [User_id]  should NEVER be duplicated.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` seems like it would be the right answer here. @ggon . perhaps you need to supply us some sample data and expected result so we can see why this "ism't working".

Comment: @ggon So you need `[UserContact_Type]`  3  or `NULL`. Yes, then you need `LEFT JOIN`, don't omit it.

Answer (score 0):

To skip the `null` values, try to use `INNER JOIN` :

```
SELECT  u.User_id, c.UserContact_Description 
    FROM Table.user AS u

    INNER JOIN Table.userContact as c
      ON u.User_id = c.User_id
         AND c.UserContact_Type = 3
```

To get all values related to your criteria, try to use `LEFT JOIN` :

```
SELECT  u.User_id, c.UserContact_Description 
    FROM Table.user AS u

    LEFT JOIN Table.userContact as c
      ON u.User_id = c.User_id
         AND c.UserContact_Type = 3
```

Comment: Same problem as the answer above.
I have no problem with the NULL results in column [UserContact_Description]. I just want to bring every  [User_id]  in Table.user but avoid its duplicates.
If theres no  [User_id]  related to an [UserContact_Type] = 3, just bring me NULL, but dont duplicate the [User_id] for those who has.

Comment: Theres no such thing because as i ask to show [UserContact_Description] only when [UserContact_Type] is equal to 3. And each [User_id] has no correlation with more than one [UserContact_Type] = 3. But it has with other types, and thats what make duplicate results with NULL rows.